# What does this mysterious code do?

Tags: java

My code:

```
public void mysterious() {
    int x = 1;
    x = x++ / ++x;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

whats the answer?

Comment: I always get `0` as expected so I don't know why you get `2`.

Comment: I was about to say 0, you get 1 / 3 which is 0.33 which when cast to int (in this case) is 0.

Comment: `1 / 3` is 0 in integer division, no casting required. ;)

Comment: Simple way is to replace your expression with this: `x = x / (2 + x) // x++ / ++x`

Answer (score 4):

```
int x = 1;
x = x++ / ++x;
System.out.println(x);
```

**Evaluation is done left-to-right: -**

- First x++ is evaluated.. So, it will be `1`
- Then x will be incremented by 1.. For Post Increment..
- Then `++x` is evaluated.. Which will be 3 (As x was incremented after `x++`)

**So, basically, your above code is equivalent to: -**

```
int x = 1;
int a = x++;   // a = 1, x = 2
int b = ++x;   // b = 3, x = 3
x = a / b;     // x = 1 / 3
System.out.println(x); // Prints 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation of this expression is performed left to right. This expression is equivalent to this one after increment evaluation:

```
x = 1/3;
```

thus, the answer is 0;

Answer (score 0):

```
public void mysterious() {
    int x = 1;
    x = x++ / ++x;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

`x = 1;`   // assignment of integer value 1 to variable x

```
x = x++ / ++x;
```

Let break the above statement into 2 diff statements.

`x++` - PostIncrement, x's value is incremented by 1, so its value is 2 now, then

`x++` - PreIncrement, x's value is once again incremented and assigned to x on the Left hand side, so its 3 now.

```
System.out.println(x);
```

So it will be `1/3`, that will lead to `0`, if you use `double` instead of int, you will see that the value is `0.33333333`